# eRROR ON "Go" keyword in hibernate while running native query

Tags: hibernate

I am having an issue with generated query by reading .sql file and executing via hibernate.

Steps of error generation: Read the .sql file.  --> and create SQLQuery object of hibernate. -->execute the query. follow this snippet assuming hibernate session is present. I use hibernate 4.2.0.1.Final and Spring's 3.2.1.RELEASE version.

```
        // optimization.sql is having 1500 lines of Indexes script...     
        private static String resource = "/com/iqx/storage/queries/optimization.sql";        
        InputStream is = ExcelResourceReader.class.getResourceAsStream(resource);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((str = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(str + "\n");
        }
        bf.close();     
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sb.toString());
        query.executeUpdate();
```

This is just a single index example on "optimization.sql". There are about 100 Indexes in the file

```
        IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM SYS.INDEXES WHERE NAME = N'QBI_TIDX')
            DROP INDEX [QBI_TIDX] ON [ABSTRACT_TABLE]
        GO
        CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [QBI_TIDX] ON [ABSTRACT_TABLE] 
        (
            [QUOTE_FK] ASC,
            [ID] ASC
        )
        INCLUDE ( [VERSION],
        [DESCRIPTION]) WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
        GO
```

Error: "12:04:10.996 [main] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 102, SQLState: S0001
12:04:10.996 [main] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Incorrect syntax near 'GO'."

But when I run the generated output (Stringbuffer) using SQLServer Studio, it doesn't give me this problem.

If anybody has an idea, please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `GO` is not a SQL statement, it's only a "delimiter" used by the Microsoft *tools* and it's not understood by the server itself.

Comment: Thanks. I ran the same indexes query without "Go" statement. It runs without any errors. But, I am not sure whether or not it is the right approach.